# Upgrading Enterprise library - v1.0 to v4.1

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I have an application currently using the 1.0 version of ent-lib, which I am trying to use with ent-lib 4.1. It is currently using these blocks: Common, Data, Logging, Security.Cryptography, Security and Configuration. I have so far been sitting with the source of both ent-lib 1.0 and 4.1 trying to find out which classes correspond to which, but this isn't proving to successful.

1) The configuration block seems to be missing in the 4.1 version, is it simply divided among the other more specific blocks?

2) I am trying to find information on what parts of the code is merely a matter on swapping out names, and where I have to rewrite the functionality. Especially classes which have been renamed or put in a different location. Is there any good way to do this? Any documentation which can be used?

3) What is the 4.1 solution for DBCommandWrapper and the events in the Security namespace?

Comment: 1.0 to 4.1 is less of an upgrade, and more of a rewrite. Even 2.0 to 4.1 might have been an upgrade, but they learned too much since version 1 for such a huge jump to be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's gone.

3a) Just use DBCommand on the data side.  The Wrapper stuff is all gone.